# Where is the main immigration bureau in Ho Chi Minh City?

Tags: vietnam

I would like to know where is the main immigration bureau in Ho Chi Minh City, Vietnam.

Spanning search on several websites, I have learned (and I might have learned wrong) that three different immigration bureaus in HCMC:

- 196 Nguyen Thi Minh Khai, Ward 6, District 3
- 161 Nguyen Du Str, Ben Thanh Ward, District 1
- 254 Nguyễn Trãi, Ward 1 District 1

### My problem

I didn't find a clear explanation about which is the main one (from the material I have read I assume it is one of the last two).

### My question

Where is the main immigration bureau in Ho Chi Minh City?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A Google search for "Immigration Offices in Ho Chi Minh City" lists  the Ministry for Public Security, Department of Immigration at 254 Nguyễn Trãi, Phường Nguyễn Cư Trinh, Quận 1, Hồ Chí Minh.

The accompanying photos show service counters and a large waiting area. Reviews on Google suggest that the staff are knowledgeable and speak good English.

You could start there. If you're wrong, the office at 161 Nguyen Du Str is only a few minutes walk away.